# How did my question become extremely popular within a few minutes?

Tags: discussion, questions

I [asked a question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/56519/how-to-share-the-look-back-video-from-facebook) about something on Facebook which at first had very little views/activity. I got an answer, it solved my problem, and I accepted it. 3 hours later, I come back and there's now suddenly over 2,000 views!!!!! I'm a very active member of Stack Overflow, and rarely do I ever even hit 1,000 views, after months. But in 3 hours, over 2,000 views???

I'm assuming that TONS of other people had this same problem, and somewhere along the line, a link to my question must have been shared somewhere. Obviously most likely on Facebook its self.

Where and how did this suddenly pop to an extremely popular question? In even just the last 10 minutes, it's gone up over 1,000 more views. I started writing this question when I saw it hit 1,200, now it's 2,500 - and seems to be climbing at a rate of at least 150 views per minute. Can any moderators see where these views are coming from?

Comment: After 30 minutes, now it's over 5,000 views.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google indexes Stack Exchange pages pretty rapidly. So queries such as "How to share look back on Facebook" will have your post on the front page of a Google Search.